# Vim: change label for specific tab

Tags: vim

Say I have a bunch of tabs open in Vim, with a tabline looks something like this:

`1 v/file1.py   2 t/file.py   1 t/file.py 1 o/otherfile.py`

See how two tabs both say "t/file.py"? Those are different files, they just get turned into the same tab label.

In my workflow the tab titles are often ambiguous (yay for Chef naming *everything* "default.rb") or unhelpful ("I know one of these 8 tabs with 4 buffers each has that file I'm looking for...").

I'd like to rename the tabs to indicate what they logically represent:

`1 homepage_view  2 tests  1 homepage_template  1 o/otherfile.py`

I'm fine with tabs defaulting to a filename-based label, as long as I'm free to change it once the tab is created.

How can I do this in Vim?

Comment: I do not have time to experiment right now, but see `:help setting-tabline` (for vim in a terminal) or `:help setting-guitablabel` (for gvim).  You could write a function that checks for a tab-local variable and returns either that or some default.  Then, after opening a tab, `:let t:mytablabel = 'homepage_template'`.

Comment: [This answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9881/7706) may be helpful, but Vimscript knowledge is required, and it is not helpful if you simply want to add a static label to the tab title provided by the default Vim behaviour (i.e., `+` for modified buffer, truncating filenames, etc.). (Which is what I need, hence [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38811/what-is-the-default-tabline-function).)

Answer (score 20):

There's a nice little plugin called [Taboo](https://github.com/gcmt/taboo.vim) that makes this easy. Just install it and then you can change the tab title with:

```
:TabooRename My Tab Title
```

You can look at the source code for that plugin if you're interested in writing your own solution.

Comment: `Taboo` is fantastic. `TabooReset` and `TabooRename` literally toggles two "modes" of the Tab-line ==> a *named* tab by _Taboo_, and an auto-named tab by Vim. This replicates the "_named Windows_" from Tmux perfectly. Better still, tabs named under Taboo can be restored using [Startify](https://github.com/mhinz/vim-startify) (or under any other session-saving tools).

Answer (score 11):

For gvim, see

```
:help 'guitablabel'
:help setting-guitablabel
```

Set the option to an expression that evaluates to `t:mytablabel` (a tab-local variable) if it exists, or else to an empty string (meaning to use the default):

```
:set guitablabel=%{exists('t:mytablabel')?t:mytablabel\ :''}
```

Maybe that is already too complicated, or maybe you want to get fancier.  In that case, define a function:

```
function! GuiTabLabel()
  return exists('t:mytablabel') ? t:mytablabel : ''
endfunction
:set guitablabel=%{GuiTabLabel()}
:set go+=e
```

Then, in any tab where you want to override the default, do something like

```
:let t:mytablabel = 'homepage_template'
```

If you are using vim in a terminal, not gvim, then you have to set the `'tabline'` option instead of `'guitablable'`.  This is a little more complicated, since you need a single expression that includes labels for all the open tabs.  There is a complete example under

```
:help setting-tabline
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative quick hack, without installing anything. You can create a small window with a named buffer like this.

```
:1split Hello World
```

[image: An image showing a terminal with named tabs]

Caveat 1: The small window must be selected before going to another tab if you want the name to show up.

Caveat 2: ":1split Name" won't show a tab name unless you have more than one tab open.